# Which event is triggered when we use ref.push to write in firebase database javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, insert

When we are working in firebase using javascript which event is triggered after we insert data using ref.push or ref.set.
I wanted to know if my data is inserted or not

I also wanted to throw an error when user have disconnected from internet while inserting data in firebase

I haven't seen any function or any method in internet which tells me about if data is successfully inserted or not.

Comment: `push` and `set` returns a Promise.

Answer (score 1):

This functions Promise-based, so you can use try/catch:

```
try {
  firebase.push(data) // or set
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error) // here is error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Realtime Database doesn't consider a lack of internet connection an error condition. Instead it continues to work to its best ability in the given conditions.

When you perform a write operation (with `set`, `push`, `update`, or `remove`) while there is no internet connectivity:

1. The first client fires local events immediately, so that your app can update the UI for the new/updated data.
2. It then queues the write operation for delivery once the connection is restored.
3. Once the connection is restored, the client sends any pending write operations it has in the order in which the client performed them.
4. It then handles the response from the server, which (if the server rejects the operation because of security rules) may lead to firing more local events so that the app can put the UI back into the correct sate.
5. And it then finally calls any completion listeners, and resolves or rejects the promise for the `set()`, `push()`, `update()`, or `remove()` method.

You'll note that there is no error raised at any point for a lack of an internet connection.

If you don't want to send any data to the local queue when the app has no internet connection, it's best to detect if the Firebase client is connected to the server. You can do this by [listening to the `.info/connected` pseudo-node](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/offline-capabilities#section-connection-state). This covers more than just having an internet connection btw, but also cases where the internet connections works but the client can't reach Firebase. The best practice here is to use a "global" listener for this status, and disable the relevant UI elements if the client is not connected.